# How to select rows using only number previous loaded rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a table with some rows

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_t;

CREATE TABLE test_t(
    test_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    test_name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_t (test_id, test_name) VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO test_t (test_id, test_name) VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO test_t (test_id, test_name) VALUES (3, 'c');
INSERT INTO test_t (test_id, test_name) VALUES (4, 'd');

SELECT * FROM test_t;
```

Them i load a half of rows

```
SELECT * FROM test_t LIMIT 2;
```

After that i need to load all other rows, but all what i know about previous operation is that i load only 2 rows

So i got only the number of already loaded rows = 2

So know i got a number or rows from previous loading, but not the values of loaded rows

and i want to load all the last rows

Can i do that with such a query?

```
SELECT * FROM test_t OFFSET 2;
```

As i see know, in PGAdmin, when i run this query all the time i get the same result. Wont it return some day an another result? Some random rows, for example?

This is a little example, in fact i got a big table with 800_000_000 values, and i load half of them, it spend many days, and now i want to stop loading, stop project, update code and continue loading from this table, but i dont want to load it again from start, i want to load only another half of table, and all i know is the number of already loaded rows

Is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_t OFFSET 2;
```

Suit for such a case?

Comment: There is no such thing as "*row with position 100 000 000*" - rows in a relational database are not sorted.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is correct.  Technically you can say ```select * from table offset 100000000``` but that will return a random set of rows.  You need to have order by to make sense.  ```select * from table order by column offset 1000000000```

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson Ragnarsson, i just tried, but every time i do request with `select * from table offset 100000000` it returns the same rows in pgAdmin

Comment: Of course it returns the same rows, if your run the same statement again

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, if i run the same statement every time, will the `select * from table offset 100000000` work right for situation when i use the same query? Can i use it in my case?

Comment: No it won't (or at least you can not rely on that)  because you did not use an `ORDER BY`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, so i need add `ORDER BY` to my query and it will work as i want? Is it enough?

Comment: @Arseniy, where are you want to use this code ? if you use this into reporting then you can use parameter after offset.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The query without `ORDER BY` won't always return the same result, even if the table is never modified. For that, you'd have to set `synchronize_seqscans = off`. So there are really no guarantees.

Comment: @Arseniy can you add the table structure to your question? (a create table statement would suffice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select * 
from table_name 
offset 100000000
```

But better use ORDER BY not to get random values in result

```
select * 
from table_name 
ORDER BY some_column
offset 100000000
```